# Pass variables between Pool workers?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, infinite-loop, pool

I have a pool of 2 processes. Process #1 with infinite loop. I need to stop infinite loop in process #1 when something happens in process #2. How to pass info from process #1 to process #2?

```
def do_smth(value):
  a = 0
  if value == "1":
    while 1:
      time.sleep(0.5)
      print("process_1", a)
      if a == 10: break
  if value == "2":
    while a < 10:
      time.sleep(0.5)
      print("process_2", a)
      a +=1

def make_a_pool(all):
  with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2) as pool:
      pool.map(do_smth, all)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    all = ["1", "2"]
    make_a_pool(all)
```

Comment: Off-topic: `all` is the name of [a built-in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all), so you should refrain from defining it to be something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you wish is to share a full variable, and not just a stop condition for an infinite loop, you may use `multiprocessing.Value()`. Keep in mind you have to initialize the value differently, as `multiprocessing.Pool` cannot pass around synchronization primitives that can't be pickled:

```
import functools
import multiprocessing
import time

def initialize_a(a_):
    global a
    a = a_

def do_smth(value):
  if value == "1":
    while True:
      time.sleep(0.5)
      print("process_1", a.value)
      if a.value >= 10: break
  if value == "2":
    while a.value < 10:
      time.sleep(0.5)
      print("process_2", a.value)
      a.value +=1

def make_a_pool(all):
  a = multiprocessing.Value("i")
  a.value = 0
  with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2,
                            initializer=initialize_a, initargs=(a,)) as pool:
    pool.map(do_smth, all)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    all = ["1", "2"]
    make_a_pool(all)
```

Output:

```
process_2 0
process_1 0
process_1 1
process_2 1
process_2 2
process_1 2
process_1 3
process_2 3
process_1 4
process_2 4
process_2 5
process_1 5
process_1 6
process_2 6
process_1 7
process_2 7
process_1 8
process_2 8
process_2 9
process_1 9
```

I do not need to use any lock, as only one process changes the value, otherwise, you need to use `Value.lock()`.

Comment: Very generally speaking I think you may be wrong about not needing a `Lock` (because there *are* two processes *reading* the shared variable's value). The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Value) specifically mentions that "Operations like += which involve a read and write are not atomic" and then goes on to describe a proper way to do it.

Comment: @mart it's not atomic, but it doesn't need to be. In case of a collision you'll either see the previous state or the new state, and it doesn't matter which. The problem arises when you have two writers using the non atomic operation (which by itself includes a read and a write). The single write operation is atomic and will not cause memory corruption or show wrong values in the reader.

Comment: The point I was trying to make was merely that even though it doesn't matter much in this toy example, it might in real world code.

Comment: @mart on any real world single writer multiple readers - it will not make any difference. If there are multiple writer processes, the lock will be needed of course, as I started at the end :-)

Comment: I disagree. Imagine a reader that needs to stop doing something after a certain value has been reached, but it happens to read the value at the same time that it's in the middle of non-atomically being incremented, so keeps on going.

Comment: @martineau since processes are not synchronized, the reader might as well take the lock and read it before it's being incremented. The result is the exactly the same. Any external synchronisation that guarantees order will also apply over that line of code without needing an extra lock. All the documentation says is that the `+=` operation is not atomic, just like it's relevant in multithreading or anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is to use an [`Event`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Event). Keep in mind you have to initialize the event differently, as `multiprocessing.Pool` cannot pass around synchronization primitives that can't be pickled:

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def initialize_event(e):
    global event
    event = e

def do_smth(value):
  a = 0
  if value == "1":
    while not event.is_set():
      time.sleep(0.5)
      print("process_1", a)
      if a == 10: break
  if value == "2":
    while a < 10:
      time.sleep(0.5)
      print("process_2", a)
      a +=1
      if a == 5: event.set()

def make_a_pool(all):
  event = multiprocessing.Event()
  with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2,
                            initializer=initialize_event, initargs=(event,)
                            ) as pool:
    pool.map(do_smth, all)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    all = ["1", "2"]
    make_a_pool(all)
```

Output (you didn't advance `a` on `value=="1"`):

```
process_2 0
process_1 0
process_1 0
process_2 1
process_1 0
process_2 2
process_2 3
process_1 0
process_2 4
process_1 0
process_2 5
process_2 6
process_2 7
process_2 8
process_2 9
```